# Check in NodeJS JavaScript runtime code if running as CommonJS or ESM Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I am writing a JS function that could be used in both CommonJS & ESM Module system.

But it would do something different depending on which it ran in.

Is there any way to test in runtime code which system we are in?

Comment: "*it would do something different depending on which it ran in*" - please don't! Write two different functions in two different files, and publish your package so that either will be imported.

Comment: "*I am writing a JS function*" - do you mean you want to publish a library as a package?

Answer (score -1):

If the following condition is true, then you are running using CommonJS modules:

```js
typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports !== 'undefined'
```

However, to check if you are using ECMAScript modules, you would use this condition:

```js
typeof import !== 'undefined' && typeof export !== 'undefined'
```

---

You can use it in your code like this:

```js
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  // CommonJS code path
} else if (typeof import !== 'undefined' && typeof export !== 'undefined') {
  // ESM code path
}
```

---

> Note: I normally use TypeScript, and this is the method that I use. When TypeScript gets compiled to JavaScript, it changes form. However, I believe this is the best solution, and should be totally compatible with regular plain JS

Comment: `typeof import !== 'undefined' && typeof export !== 'undefined'` throws a syntax error.